# ASPNET vNext Beta 8 localization

Tags: localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any way in MVC 6 (beta 8) application to get CultureInfo object, based on request Accept-Language header?

I have found we should use (not sure in which beta):

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
    {
        new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider()
    }
});
```

in startup class, but how about control? How this information is injected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question. The CultureInfo is available in controller action methods using:

```
var cultureInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

The catch was than Accept-Language header is case sensitive. I needed to provide lt-LT instead of lt-lt.